# How to solve this trigonometric equation: $\sin3x+\sin5x=\sin6x+\sin2x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $x$
$$\sin3x+\sin5x=\sin6x+\sin2x$$

I tried: $$\sin3x+\sin(2x+3x)=\sin(2*3x)+\sin2x$$
$$\sin3x+\sin2x*\cos3x+\cos2x*\sin3x=2\sin3x*\cos3x+\sin2x$$
... After that i have no idea what to do. If i try with $\sin(x+2x)$ or something similar, it becomes even more scarry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** use the formula $$\sin x+\sin y = 2\sin {x+y\over 2}\cdot \cos{x-y\over 2}$$
and $$\cos x-\cos y = -2\sin {x+y\over 2}\cdot \sin{x-y\over 2}$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the equation as
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}\iff{}}\sin(4x-x)+\sin(4x+x)=\sin(4x+2x)+\sin(4x-2x)\\
&\iff  2\sin 4x\cos x=2\sin 4x\cos 2x\iff\begin{cases}\sin 4x=0\\\cos x=\cos 2x
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Can you proceed from here?